# Running in to issue with script I'm attempting to adapt

Tags: powershell

I found this script I'm looking to use to send emails to users when their passwords expire.
This is the area I'm running in to issues with:

```
param(
    # $smtpServer Enter Your SMTP Server Hostname or IP Address
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=0)]
    [ValidateNwotNull()]
    [string]$smtpServer,
    # Notify Users if Expiry Less than X Days
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [int]$expireInDays,
    # From Address, eg "IT Support <support@domain.com>"
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2)]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [string]$from,
    [Parameter(Position=3)]
    [switch]$logging,
    # Log File Path
    [Parameter(Position=4)]
    [string]$logPath,
    # Testing Enabled
    [Parameter(Position=5)]
    [switch]$testing,
    # Test Recipient, eg recipient@domain.com
    [Parameter(Position=6)]
    [string]$testRecipient,
    # Output more detailed status to console
    [Parameter(Position=7)]
    [switch]$status,
    # Log file recipient
    [Parameter(Position=8)]
    [string]$reportto,
    # Notification Interval
    [Parameter(Position=9)]
    [array]$interval,
    )
# Time / Date Info
$start = [datetime]::Now
$midnight = $start.Date.AddDays(1)
$timeToMidnight = New-TimeSpan -Start $start -end $midnight.Date
$midnight2 = $start.Date.AddDays(2)
$timeToMidnight2 = New-TimeSpan -Start $start -end $midnight2.Date
# System Settings
$textEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$today = $start
# End System Settings

# Load AD Module
try{
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch{
    Write-Warning "Unable to load Active Directory PowerShell Module"
}
# Set Output Formatting - Padding characters
$padVal = "20"
Write-Output "Script Loaded"
Write-Output "*** Settings Summary ***"
$smtpServerLabel = "SMTP Server".PadRight($padVal," ")
$expireInDaysLabel = "Expire in Days".PadRight($padVal," ")
$fromLabel = "From".PadRight($padVal," ")
$testLabel = "Testing".PadRight($padVal," ")
$testRecipientLabel = "Test Recipient".PadRight($padVal," ")
$logLabel = "Logging".PadRight($padVal," ")
$logPathLabel = "Log Path".PadRight($padVal," ")
$reportToLabel = "Report Recipient".PadRight($padVal," ")
$interValLabel = "Intervals".PadRight($padval," ")
# Testing Values
if($testing)
{
    if(($testRecipient) -eq $null)
    {
        Write-Output "No Test Recipient Specified"
        Exit
    }
}
# Logging Values
if($logging)
{
    if(($logPath) -eq $null)
    {
        $logPath = $PSScriptRoot
    }
}
# Output Summary Information
Write-Output "$smtpServerLabel : $smtpServer"
Write-Output "$expireInDaysLabel : $expireInDays"
Write-Output "$fromLabel : $from"
Write-Output "$logLabel : $logging"
Write-Output "$logPathLabel : $logPath"
Write-Output "$testLabel : $testing"
Write-Output "$testRecipientLabel : $testRecipient"
Write-Output "$reportToLabel : $reportto"
Write-Output "$interValLabel : $interval"
Write-Output "*".PadRight(25,"*")
# Get Users From AD who are Enabled, Passwords Expire and are Not Currently Expired
$users = get-aduser -filter {(Enabled -eq $true) -and (PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false)} -properties Name, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, EmailAddress | where { $_.passwordexpired -eq $false }
# Count Users
$usersCount = ($users | Measure-Object).Count
Write-Output "Found $usersCount User Objects"
# Collect Domain Password Policy Information
$defaultMaxPasswordAge = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy -ErrorAction Stop).MaxPasswordAge.Days 
Write-Output "Domain Default Password Age: $defaultMaxPasswordAge"
# Collect Users
$colUsers = @()
# Process Each User for Password Expiry
Write-Output "Process User Objects"
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    # Store User information
    $Name = $user.Name
    $emailaddress = $user.emailaddress
    $passwordSetDate = $user.PasswordLastSet
    $samAccountName = $user.SamAccountName
    $pwdLastSet = $user.PasswordLastSet
    # Check for Fine Grained Password
    $maxPasswordAge = $defaultMaxPasswordAge
    $PasswordPol = (Get-AduserResultantPasswordPolicy $user) 
    if (($PasswordPol) -ne $null)
    {
        $maxPasswordAge = ($PasswordPol).MaxPasswordAge.Days
    }
    # Create User Object
    $userObj = New-Object System.Object
    $expireson = $pwdLastSet.AddDays($maxPasswordAge)
    $daysToExpire = New-TimeSpan -Start $today -End $Expireson
    # Round Expiry Date Up or Down
    if(($daysToExpire.Days -eq "0") -and ($daysToExpire.TotalHours -le $timeToMidnight.TotalHours))
    {
        $userObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name UserMessage -Value "today."
    }
    if(($daysToExpire.Days -eq "0") -and ($daysToExpire.TotalHours -gt $timeToMidnight.TotalHours) -or ($daysToExpire.Days -eq "1") -and ($daysToExpire.TotalHours -le $timeToMidnight2.TotalHours))
    {
        $userObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name UserMessage -Value "tomorrow."
    }
    if(($daysToExpire.Days -ge "1") -and ($daysToExpire.TotalHours -gt $timeToMidnight2.TotalHours))
    {
        $days = $daysToExpire.TotalDays
        $days = [math]::Round($days)
        $userObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name UserMessage -Value "in $days days."
    }
    $daysToExpire = [math]::Round($daysToExpire.TotalDays)
    $userObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name UserName -Value $samAccountName
    $userObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $Name
    $userObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name EmailAddress -Value $emailAddress
    $userObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name PasswordSet -Value $pwdLastSet
    $userObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name DaysToExpire -Value $daysToExpire
    $userObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name ExpiresOn -Value $expiresOn
    # Add userObj to colusers array
    $colUsers += $userObj
}
# Count Users
$colUsersCount = ($colUsers | Measure-Object).Count
Write-Output "$colusersCount Users processed"
# Select Users to Notify
$notifyUsers = $colUsers | where { $_.DaysToExpire -le $expireInDays}
$notifiedUsers = @()
$notifyCount = ($notifyUsers | Measure-Object).Count
Write-Output "$notifyCount Users with expiring passwords within $expireInDays Days"
# Process notifyusers
foreach ($user in $notifyUsers)
{
    # Email Address
    $samAccountName = $user.UserName
    $emailAddress = $user.EmailAddress
    # Set Greeting Message
    $name = $user.Name
    $messageDays = $user.UserMessage
    # Subject Setting
    $subject="Your password will expire $messageDays"
    # Email Body Set Here, Note You can use HTML, including Images.
    # examples here https://youtu.be/iwvQ5tPqgW0 
    $body ="
    <font face=""verdana"">
    Dear $name,
    <p> Your Password will expire $messageDays<br>
    To change your password on a PC press CTRL ALT Delete and choose Change Password <br>
    <p> If you are using a MAC you can now change your password via Web Mail. <br>
    Login to <a href=""https://mail.domain.com/owa"">Web Mail</a> click on Options, then Change Password.
    <p> Don't forget to Update the password on your Mobile Devices as well!
    <p>Thanks, <br> 
    </P>
    IT Support
    <a href=""mailto:support@domain.com""?Subject=Password Expiry Assistance"">support@domain.com</a> | 0123 456 78910
    </font>"
    # If Testing Is Enabled - Email Administrator
    if($testing)
    {
        $emailaddress = $testRecipient
    } # End Testing
    # If a user has no email address listed
    if(($emailaddress) -eq $null)
    {
        $emailaddress = $testRecipient    
    }# End No Valid Email
    $samLabel = $samAccountName.PadRight($padVal," ")
    try{
        # If using interval paramter - follow this section
        if($interval)
        {
            $daysToExpire = [int]$user.DaysToExpire
            # check interval array for expiry days
            if(($interval) -Contains($daysToExpire))
            {
                # if using status - output information to console
                if($status)
                {
                    Write-Output "Sending Email : $samLabel : $emailAddress"
                }
                # Send message - if you need to use SMTP authentication watch this video https://youtu.be/_-JHzG_LNvw
                Send-Mailmessage -smtpServer $smtpServer -from $from -to $emailaddress -subject $subject -body $body -bodyasHTML -priority High -Encoding $textEncoding -ErrorAction Stop
                $user | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SendMail -Value "OK"
            }
            else
            {
                # if using status - output information to console
                # No Message sent
                if($status)
                {
                    Write-Output "Sending Email : $samLabel : $emailAddress : Skipped - Interval"
                }
                $user | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SendMail -Value "Skipped - Interval"
            }
        }
        else
        {
            # if not using interval paramter - follow this section
            # if using status - output information to console
            if($status)
            {
                Write-Output "Sending Email : $samLabel : $emailAddress"
            }
            Send-Mailmessage -smtpServer $smtpServer -from $from -to $emailaddress -subject $subject -body $body -bodyasHTML -priority High -Encoding $textEncoding -ErrorAction Stop
            $user | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SendMail -Value "OK"
        }
    }
    catch{
        # error section
        $errorMessage = $_.exception.Message
        # if using status - output information to console
        if($status)
        {
           $errorMessage
        }
        $user | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SendMail -Value $errorMessage    
    }
    $notifiedUsers += $user
}
if($logging)
{
    # Create Log File
    Write-Output "Creating Log File"
    $day = $today.Day
    $month = $today.Month
    $year = $today.Year
    $date = "$day-$month-$year"
    $logFileName = "$date-PasswordLog.csv"
    if(($logPath.EndsWith("\")))
    {
       $logPath = $logPath -Replace ".$"
    }
    $logFile = $logPath, $logFileName -join "\"
    Write-Output "Log Output: $logfile"
    $notifiedUsers | Export-CSV $logFile
    if($reportTo)
    {
        $reportSubject = "Password Expiry Report"
        $reportBody = "Password Expiry Report Attached"
        try{
            Send-Mailmessage -smtpServer $smtpServer -from $from -to $reportTo -subject $reportSubject -body $reportbody -bodyasHTML -priority High -Encoding $textEncoding -Attachments $logFile -ErrorAction Stop 
        }
        catch{
            $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
            Write-Output $errorMessage
        }
    }
}
$notifiedUsers | select UserName,Name,EmailAddress,PasswordSet,DaysToExpire,ExpiresOn | sort DaystoExpire | FT -autoSize

$stop = [datetime]::Now
$runTime = New-TimeSpan $start $stop
Write-Output "Script Runtime: $runtime"
# End
```

When I run the code it produces this error:

```
PS C:\> .\ExpiredPassswordv6.ps1 -smtpServer smtp.office365.com -expireInDays 14 -from "TestDesk <TestDesk@gmail.com>" -logging -logPath C:\automation -testing -testRecipient testemail@gmail.com -reportto -interval 1
At C:\ExpiredPassswordv6.ps1:66 char:22
+     [array]$interval,
+                      ~
Missing expression after ','.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken

PS C:\>
```

I'm not well versed in Powershell and I cannot find any solution to this thing. There's a lot more to the script but I think I've narrowed the issue down to this location for now.

*Edit - added rest of the script

Comment: If you have no other parameter after the last one take the , away. You are currently telling PowerShell to expect another parameter but you are not providing one.

Comment: You are only showing us the `param(...)` block; not the script itself, so we have no idea what parameter `Interval` actually does and why it is supposed to be an array... Does it expect an array of integers, datetime objects or ???

Comment: I apologize, I added the rest of the script. From what I understand you're supposed to run the script like this: .\ExpiredPassswordv6.ps1 -smtpServer smtp.office365.com -expireInDays 14 -from "Testemail <Testemail@gmail.com>" -logging -logPath C:\automation -testing -testRecipient testemail@gmail.com -reportto -interval 1

If I understand correctly is should fill in the parameters. I've tried added them in to the parameter section that was initially posted but it produces a different error.

Comment: As @JonathanWaring notes above: the solution to the error shown in your post is to just remove the trailing `,` after `$interval` in the param block

Comment: Oh perfect, yup that fixes that error!
Thanks!

Comment: @Rblhunter, glad to hear the issue is solved. Note that one of the standard reasons for closing a question is "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Please consider deleting your question, as future readers are unlikely to benefit from it.